# Problems trying save tortoiseHg credentials

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Some days I go while i was learning about mercurial and TortoiseHG i made a mistake and now i have problems to save my credentials,
I tried change the next files with no good results:
-C:\Users\userA\mercurial.ini

```
[ui]
username=myuse@company.cl
password=xxxxxx
```

-C:\Users\userA\Mercurial-kiln.ini

```
[auth]
kiln.prefix=theurl
kiln.username=myuse@company.cl
kiln.username=xxxxxx
```

- %myrepo%.hg\hgrc

  [ui]
  username=myuse@company.cl
  password=xxxxxx

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ui section on global ini-file (mercurial.ini) is only your signature in commits, if not redefined later
- auth section define authorization-data on some resource only
- ui in hgrc redifine on per-repo basis data from p.1

ui-data in your case is bad - you have to use username key with value `Fname LName <e-mail>`, i.e

```
username = Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@example.net>
```

and **forget about any password here**

auth-section is also far from perfect

- you *redefine* kiln.username instead of extending
- no password (?)